# How to get Quarter Date ranges when passing quarter number and year

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement of extracting data of given quarter.

For example if I pass

```
declare @year int=2021 
declare @q int=2
```

the function should return

```
year    quarterfrom   quarterto
--------------------------------
2021     2021-04-01     2021-06-30
-----------------------------------
```

How can we achieve that in MSSQL (2012)

Comment: calendar quarters or financial/fiscal quarters? If the latter, do you wish to ASSUME they never change (because they legally can in many locations)?

Comment: @SMor Calendar quarters are actually the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some fairly trivial date maths works:

```sql
DECLARE @year int = 2021,
        @q int = 2;

SELECT @Year AS Year,
       DATEADD(MONTH, 3 * (@q-1),DATEFROMPARTS(@year,1,1)),
       EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, (3 * (@q-1))+2,DATEFROMPARTS(@year,1,1)));
```

This, of course, assumes that the quarters start on the 1st, 4th, 7th and 10th months.